# Three.js MTLLoader() only loads first objects color?

Tags: three.js

Here I have a simple script that uses Three.JS MTL Loader and OBJ loader to load a model and the material for the model. 
Now when it loads the model it only loads the first objects color and the rest it leaves white. Can anyone shed some light on what may be the cause of thise ?
Here is my code

```
            var loader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                            loader.load('http://ustarp.com/3DModels/WebsiteParts/Polished Aluminum/Underbody/11228.mtl', function (materials) {
                               materials.preload();
                               var objLoaderOfficeChair = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                               objLoaderOfficeChair.setMaterials(materials);
                               objLoaderOfficeChair.load('http://ustarp.com/3DModels/WebsiteParts/Polished Aluminum/Underbody/11228.obj', function (object) {
               object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                  if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ){
                                     x=document.getElementsByClassName("popup");  // Find the elements
                                     for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
                                        x[i].innerHTML += "<li class='mi_child'>"+child.name+"</li>";    // Change the content


                }
               }
            });
                            object.name = 'Part1';
                            object.scale.set(50,50,50);obj3d.add( object );
                            object.updateMatrix();  

                                  model2 = object;  
                              scene.add(object);                     
                });
            });
```

Here is an example of the model being shown.

http://ustarp.com/3DModels/?part=2c75cf2681788adaca63aa95ae028b22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mtl file is not formatted correctly:

```
# WaveFront *.mtl file (generated by Autodesk ATF)

newmtl 254,254,255
Ka 0.996078 0.996078 1.000000
Kd 0.996078 0.996078 1.000000
Ks 0.996078 0.996078 1.000000
Ns 1000.000000
d 1.000000

newmtl 229,31,31
Ka 0.898039 0.121569 0.121569
Kd 0.898039 0.121569 0.121569
Ks 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ns 1000.000000
d 1.000000
```

`newmtl` takes a string to be used as an identifier.

**Edit**

What you can do is replace the string `254,254,255` with the string `white` and the string `229,31,31` with the string `redish` in the mtl file and the obj file.

Comment: What do you sugesst ?

Comment: I'm generating these straight from AutoDesk

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically ?

Comment: Maybe regex with php all the MTL files that get uploaded and replace the RGB with Color Names ?

Comment: yes you can do this but I would try to find out why does AutoDesk creates such names and maybe try to fix it.